# New Macbook suddenly shut down when using Virtual Box

Tags: macos, crash, power, virtualbox

My MacBook Pro 2019 suddenly powered off when I was booting ubuntu on virtual box. The only other program running on my laptop was the  App Store. How can I find out the reason of power failure? It's fine if it's just software error, but I read this might also come from battery flaws.

Comment: See your battery status using these answers https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/427/are-there-any-apps-to-diagnose-a-macbook-battery/430#430 (hold alt and click on battery status in menu bar.). Was there a kernel panic popup after you restated? If it was search [tag:kernel-panic] for isolating the issue. If not, I am afraid you'll have to see console.app or some other log files(I dont know which ones) in ~/Library etc to see the crash causes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found questions describing similar situation. Crash seems to happen randomly when using virtualbox on mojave, so I think it might due to bugs of virtualbox.

Comment: You can also give this apple doc a read if you want [Understanding and Debugging Kernel Panics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2063/_index.html) (use @ to notify people )